# Width of text by FormattedText.Width is different from the original width

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I have a formattedText which I am placing on a canvas of WPF using DrawText method.

```
FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
    drawString,
    CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
    FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface(fontName),
    numeralHeight,
    Brushes.Black);
```

Now, my problem is that I want to calculate the width of this text in mm(For example: I want to calculate width of 1000 or Test-Text) but Width of text by FormattedText.Width is different from the original width.

Comment: How do you calculate the width in mm? What is the "original width"? Please provide some details about what you tried and what exactly went wrong.

Comment: How are you checking the Width? Using `Width`? `ActualWidth`? What has changed?

Comment: I am taking the print on paper this is how the actual width in mm is measured which is different from value of FormattedText.Width in code.

Comment: @Clemens : Any idea about this?

Comment: WPF uses "device-independant units", which are 1/96th of an inch (a unit corresponds to one pixel if your display is set to 96 DPI). An inch is 25.4 mm, so one unit is 25.4 / 96 mm. Not sure if the printer's DPI setting also has to be taken into account.